# (Dirent.h), Listar archivos txt de carpeta

Tags: c++

quiero utilizar la libreria dirent.h para listar todos los nombres de archivos de una carpeta (archivos tipo .txt) pero que asi mismo como se vayan listando tambien se vayan guardando en una variable tipo string que asi mismo la este abriendo en modo lectura con un ifstream. No se si me haya hecho entender, el objetivo es listar cierta información de unos archivos .txt cuyos nombres son numeros muyyy grandes, lo intente con un for pero este avanza bastante lento, adjunto el codigo del for.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <dirent.h> //aqui la libreria que quiero utilizar.
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

long int x;
string z;

for(x=60400000; x<10000000000; ++x){
string result;
stringstream convert; //Convert de int a string 
convert<<x;//Señalamos la variable a convertir
result=convert.str();//x queda guardada en una variable result con los 
                     //valores de x
z=result+".txt";
/*cout<<z;*///Descomentar para ver el proceso de busqueda.
ifstream file(z.c_str());//Abre la variable z que depende del for.

if (!file){
}

else{
string a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i;
file >>a>>b>>c>>d>>e>>f>>g>>h>>i;//Doy un nombre a cada linea del archivo
cout<<"Nombre: "<<a<<"  "<<"Celular: "<<c<<"  "<<"Fecha de pago: "<<h<<" "<<endl;//Imprimo las lineas que necesito especificamente
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con `dirent.h` puedes conseguir un listado del contenido de un directorio de forma sencilla:

```
DIR *dir;
dirent *ent;
if (DIR* dir = opendir("[ruta directorio]"))
{
  while (dirent* ent = readdir(dir) )
    std::cout << ent->d_name << '\n';
  closedir (dir);
}
```

Ahora bien, en ese listado encontrarás que se cuelan también las carpetas, entre ellas `.` y  `..`. Si dispones de un mecanismo sencillo para identificar los archivos... por ejemplo que en esa carpeta únicamente haya archivos o que éstos sean los únicos compuestos por dígitos puedes usar esa característica para filtrar la información que necesitas.

Un ejemplo (usando el estándar C++11) para verificar que todos los caracteres sean dígitos numéricos:

```
#include <cctype>

while (dirent* ent = readdir(dir) )
{
  std::string nombre = ent->name;
  bool ok = std::all_off(nombre.begin(),nombre.end(),
                         [](char c){ return std::is_digit(c); });
  if( ok )
  {
    std::cout << nombre << '\n';
    // ...
  }
}
```

Si no es así siempre puedes usar `stat.h` para inspeccionar el elemento en cuestión y así saber si es un fichero:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

bool IsFile(std::string const& path)
{
  stat path_stat;
  stat(path.c_str(), &path_stat);
  return S_ISREG(path_stat.st_mode);
}

while (dirent* ent = readdir(dir) )
{
  std::string nombre = ent->name;
  if( IsFile(nombre) )
  if( ok )
  {
    std::cout << nombre << '\n';
    // ...
  }
}
```